# How can I use a variable from web scraping?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, web-scraping

I scrape a jobs portal using this code:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')

export default function scrape() {
  ;(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch()
    const page = await browser.newPage()
    await page.goto('https://www.example.de/jobs/javascript')

    const position = await page.evaluate(() =>
      Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('h2')).map(
        position => position.innerText
      )
    )

    // const logo = await page.evaluate(() =>
    //   Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('div.job-element__logo img')).map(
    //     logo => logo.src
    //   )
    // )

    console.log(JSON.stringify(position))

    await browser.close()
  })()
}
```

I pasted a example URL here, of course I use a real one in my example. Otherwise the code should work I thought.

My question:

I can console log my extracted data under the const position. That works! But I would like to reuse it now in another react component. Which does not work...

I tried to export it as a function and import it in my component called JobCard.js. But it prints a warning saying:

Can't resolve './scraper' in .../components'.

Here is a screenshot of my data tree: [My data structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LUYSt.png)

If I put the scraper.js into components it says:

./node_modules/puppeteer/lib/WebSocketTransport.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'ws' in '/remote-jobs-app/node_modules/puppeteer/lib'

I just want to reuse the const position in another component. But I cannot get it done. Any ideas maybe?

Comment: puppeteer is a server-side module, but a React app runs on the client (browser). Two very different things. You need to set up a separate node server, then use `fetch()` on the client to request data from it. You can use the `http` module to set up a minimal server.

Comment: We're not talking about an electron app by any chance? That could work but @Chris is right, not on a web page. Not even a chrome extension.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. No its not an electron app but a web app I am building with React.js. Ok I see, I will then setup a server and do it like you guys suggested. Thx for your help.

Answer (score 0):

you can't import your **scraper** component in react.js component
when you **scraping** you are running node.js. that is not reactjs
it's a server side thing .

When you running your react.js it's a browser based thing.
i suggest you that, you scrape data and save it a file like jobdata.json and then import this in your component
then used that data

If you want dynamic result, you need a server side code. So overall design is like
you scrape the data, save it in database. make a api that and use react to show that